# OnClickListener & ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, onclicklistener

In my "OnClickListener" the "ProgressDialog" doesn't appear (code below):

```
    Button suchenbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.suchen);
    suchenbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //TODO
       public void onClick(View v) {

           ProgressDialog dialog= ProgressDialog.show(TankFinderActivity.this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);
           InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(filterTextSSD.getWindowToken(), 0);
           loadsuchen();

           dialog.dismiss();

       }

    });
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need some basic programming lactures :) Use a Async task to achive what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `loadsuchen()` is a heavy method that runs on the main thread. Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to run that method in a separate thread and call `dialog.dismiss()` at the end:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(TankFinderActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(filterTextSSD.getWindowToken(), 0);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            loadsuchen();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are showing and dismissing the dialog on the same click event of the button.it will dismiss the dialog as soon as dialog appears.change the code and try to keep dialog.dismiss() somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Button click

```
Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                openprogresdialog();
            }
        });
```

Create a this method.

```
private void openprogresdialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(
                HidekeybordActivity.this, "Testing", "Please wait...", true);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Some code........
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: This a correct answer, but I prefer to use `AsyncTask` just to make `progDailog.dismiss();` running on the main thread from inside `onPostExecute()` method :)